# stringr extract full number from string

Tags: string, r

From `?stringr::str_extract`, I tried

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract("number 123", "\\d")
 # [1] "1"
```

but I'd like the full number `123`. I couldn't find the correct regular expression, or another function to perform this task. My workaround is a bit ugly,

```
as.numeric(str_split("number 123", " ")[[1]][2])
# [1] 123
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For this particular example, the following regular expression works:

```
pat <- "(\\d)+"
as.numeric(str_extract("number 123", pat))
# [1] 123
```

If you want to only pick out numbers that terminate the text string that they are in, add a `$` to the end of the pattern above.

Comment: You only need the quotes if you're using str_match.